# Best website for free VCL components?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I am just getting back into C++ Bulder after several years.

What's currently the best web-site for free VCL components?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Jedi](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) site is great, but my favorite is [Torry's Delphi Page](http://www.torry.net/index.php), which has lots of components and resources.

[image]
<sub>(source: [torry.net](http://www.torry.net/images/torry_logo.png))</sub>

Comment: Torry's has the most components of em all, but not all are Free or have source code, so you should look to the items with a green "FWS" tag next to it noting that it is freeware with source. If you produce GPL code, you might look for "GPL" marked components.

Comment: Ah, nostalgia!

I couldn't have named either Torry or Jedi - until I read them here and they came flooding back.  Thanks.

(and something like Delphi 3000???)

Tell me is Delphi/BCB still as popular, or has it been overtaken by something else?

Comment: Heh. I love the fact the site is named after a dog.

Comment: @mawg: I'd say that Delphi is not as popular as it was in the Borland golden age. Java and C# have overtaken it (mostly because Borland's fault).

Comment: Thanks,  Averroes (plus one), I was afraid of that, but I will probably plough ahead with C++ Builder for the time being, just to save me the learning curve, and because of the additional VCL components available.

Answer (score 10):

[JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) is the standard free VCL suite.

Answer (score 1):

[Torry](http://www.torry.net/) is one of the main places you should look for free components. They have hundreds of them (you will have to be able to filter old components and take some other with a pinch of salt).

Answer (score 1):

I use Torry's Delphi Pages a lot and the JVCL too, but for me the best components are [Mike Lischke's Soft Gems](http://www.soft-gems.net/). There used to be a very nice library called the LVK Components but it was taken over by a company, [TwoDesk](http://www.twodesk.com/) and have [two licenses](http://www.twodesk.com/components/licensing/index.html) that you can choose to use (for Commercial and Open Source applications.)

Answer (score 1):

My vote is for [LMD Tools](http://www.lmdtools.com/). I use the freeware edition all the time in my personal projects, and I've used it in some commercial apps too. I've played a bit with the JVCL, but I don't find it nearly as useful as LMD Tools.

Answer (score 0):

[Delphi Super Page](http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/) - not updated for years but sometimes still useful.